# Get SelectedIndex from custom non-UI thread

Tags: c#, .net

I've encountered a problem with my application code. I've designed it to download `.xml` file from the web and read this XML file in order to download multiple files with a data it holds. However, I've programmed my app to be synchronous and that does not work well at all, so I'm trying to change my program to work mostly asynchronously when handling this task. I want the app to run this method on new thread, but I've encountered error with getting the selected index of my ReposListBox, which is on the UI thread. It's giving me a `System.InvalidOperationException`, because I am trying to access the selected index on line 13 =>  `int index = ReposListBox.SelectedIndex;`. How should I get the selected index into this integer without it producing the exception.

I am really hopeless, thanks for any help :)

```cs
private void syncButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  Thread thread = new Thread(Synchronize);
  thread.Start();
}

private void Synchronize() {
  try {
    var m_Manager = new Mods();
    var f_Synchronization = new FileSynchronization();
    var r_ListHandler = new RepositoryListHandler();

    // Download XML file and call VerifyModpacks();
    int index = ReposListBox.SelectedIndex;
    m_Manager.DownloadRepository(repos[index].Modpacks.Modpack.Source + "/index.xml");
    m_Manager.VerifyModpacks();

    m_Manager.LoadModpack(repos[index].Modpacks.Modpack.ID);

    for (int i = 0; i < repos[index].Addons.Addon.Count; i++) {
      m_Manager.VerifyMod(repos[index].Modpacks.Modpack.ID, i);
    }

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Trace.WriteLine("[Synchronize] Task Failed :: Exception [" + ex + "] thrown.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Gather the data required from the UI and pass it to the thread code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call GUI elements on the GUI thread.  Generally, it's best to do this while the GUI is blocked in your event handler, to prevent any possible race conditions with the user changing the GUI while your thread is running.

```cs
private void syncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var thread = new Thread(Synchronize);
    thread.Start(ReposListBox.SelectedIndex);
    // Or use an object or struct to pass along more than one object to the thread.
}

void Synchronize(object data)
{
    var selectedIndex = (int)data;
    Console.WriteLine(selectedIndex);
}
```

Though, for quick-n-dirty solutions, you can block in the thread while you `Invoke` some helper code on the GUI thread:

```cs
void Synchronize(object data)
{
    int orSelectedIndex = 0;
    // Invoke a small Lambda on the GUI thread to get the index
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        orSelectedIndex = ReposListBox.SelectedIndex;
    }));
    // Use our local variable in the thread
    Console.WriteLine(orSelectedIndex);
}
```